# Toggle button - show / hide information

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

Can someone help me hide / show the information when I click on the icon (arrow). I tried to use javascript, although it is not the best way, but it also didn't work.

I intend that by clicking on the image **https://img.icons8.com/android/24/000000/down.png**, the information below will be hidden and that image will change to the image of the upward facing arrow **https://img.icons8.com/android/24/000000/up.png**

When you click on the up-facing sta the information appears again and that same image is replaced by the downward-facing arrow image.

Can someone help me?

[DEMO - STACKBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-c7kd1s?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.html)

**CODE**

```
<div *ngFor="let item of data">
    <div class="d-flex flex-row"
        style="align-items: center;margin-top: 8px;padding: 16px;background: #E8EEF5 0% 0% no-repeat padding-box;border-radius: 8px;">
    <div>
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/android/24/000000/down.png" class="hide"/>
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/android/24/000000/up.png" class="hide1"/>
  </div>
    <div><span style="margin-left: 8px;" class="selectioname">{{item.name}}</span></div>
    <div style="margin-left:auto">
        <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material-outlined/24/000000/close-window.png"/>
  </div>
    </div>
    <div class="d-flex flex-row"
                style="display: flex; align-items: center; margin-top: 8px;padding: 8px;border-bottom: 1px solid #CACED5;">
        <div class="">
            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/bubbles/50/000000/check-male.png"/>
    </div>
        <div>
            <span style="margin-left: 8px;">@{{item.name}}</span>
            <div>{{item.date}}</div>
        </div>
        <div style="margin-left:auto">
            <img src="https://img.icons8.com/material/24/000000/filled-trash.png"/>
    </div>
        </div>
</div>
```

[image]

Comment: If it's suitable for you use `mat-expansion-panel` from Angular Material https://material.angular.io/components/expansion/overview . Hope that this will help.

Comment: Similar to the comment above, you could use https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/components/collapse/.

Or manually, you would use javascript:
- Add an onClick function that changes the display setting of the div as well as the two arrows images.
You can inspire yourself from this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_toggle_hide_show.asp

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, remove your styles for **hide1** class. It's better to rely on ***ngIf** directive in Angular:

```html
<img *ngIf="item.shown" src="https://img.icons8.com/android/24/000000/down.png" class="hide"/>
<img *ngIf="!item.shown" src="https://img.icons8.com/android/24/000000/up.png" class="hide1"/>
```

Then implement method to toggling **shown** property:

```js
toggle(item) {
  item.shown = !item.shown;
}
```

Now you have to bind this method to DOM event on div wrapping your arrows:

```html
<div (click)="toggle(item)">
</div>
```

And final step is to use ***ngIf** directive on other element you want to toggling:

```html
 <div class="d-flex flex-row" *ngIf="item.shown" ...
```

Answer (score 2):

HTML5 introduced a `<summary>` and `<details>` tag to allow you to toggle information.

Here's an example:

```html
<details>
<summary>Information you want shown</summary>
<p>Information you want toggled</p>
</details>
```